# Docker compose port mapping

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose yml file as in below

```yml
version: '2'
services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    links:
      - redis
    expose:
      - "6379"
  redis:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-redis
```

My goal is to forward nodejs-127.0.0.1 port 6379 to the redis host.  I can already ping redis from the nodejs machine, but the ports are not mapped.  Tried expose options, but no chance either.

Answer (score 148):

It's important to point out that all of the above solutions map the port to every interface on your machine. This is less than desirable if you have a public IP address, or your machine has an IP on a large network. Your application may be exposed to a much wider audience than you'd hoped.

```
redis:
  build:
    context:
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-redis
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:3901:3901"
```

`127.0.0.1` is the ip address that maps to the hostname `localhost` on your machine. So now your application is only exposed over that interface and since `127.0.0.1` is only accessible via your machine, you're not exposing your containers to the entire world.

The documentation explains this further and can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

---

Note: If you're using Docker for mac this will make the container listen on 127.0.0.1 on the Docker for Mac VM and will not be accessible from your localhost. If I recall correctly.

Comment: Kudo for the security prevention.

Comment: It is really important to know that the HOST:PORT mapping does not work in swarm mode. Better than opening the port is to 'expose' the port and then connect to it via the address redis:3901 (this will only be availabe to other containers in the same network)

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to specify the host port as an ephemeral port, but still restrict only to 127.0.0.1?  I tried `127.0.0.1::6379`, for example, (where 6379 is the container port) but didn't get the expected results.

Comment: @rfay I tried this and it works for me. "127.0.0.1::6379".

Comment: Note that not all machines will immediately map `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` as that's IPv4 only.  Many machines will try IPv6 first and this can cause failures in some contexts. If you want to port forward localhost for ipv6 then add `[::1]` as well.  The whole line in yaml would read: `- "[::1]:3901:3901"`

Answer (score 112):

If you want to bind to the redis port from your `nodejs` container you will have to expose that port in the `redis` container:

```yml
version: '2'
services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    links:
      - redis

  redis:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-redis
    expose:
      - "6379"
```

The `expose` tag will let you expose ports without publishing them to the host machine, but they will be exposed to the containers networks.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose

The `ports` tag will be mapping the host port with the container port *HOST:CONTAINER*

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

Comment: yes I get this part, but the issue is when go for 127.0.0.1:6379 in the nodejs container I get an error.  I am looking for an automated way for port forwarding basically.

Comment: Well, this is because they are running at different hosts/containers. Could you check if  using `redis:6379` instead of `127.0.0.1:6379` the issue solves?

Comment: yes, that works.  i need to learn the port forwarding feature though.

Comment: @z.a. I'm going to try port forwarding inside the guest using netcat e.g., https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101906/55079

Comment: @JesusTinoco Thank you! `redis:6379 instead of 127.0.0.1:6379` helped me a lot!

Comment: It is really important to know that the HOST:PORT mapping does not work in swarm mode because there 0.0.0.0 is used as the host which means that it is available from any address

Comment: How does this work? Does docker-compose up edit your hosts file?

Answer (score 11):

It seems like the other answers here all misunderstood your question.  If I understand correctly, you want to make requests to localhost:6379 (the default for redis) and have them be forwarded, automatically, to the same port on your redis container.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101906/38639 helped me get to the right answer.

First, you'll need to install the `nc` command on your image.  On CentOS, this package is called nmap-ncat, so in the example below, just replace this with the appropriate package if you are using a different OS as your base image.

Next, you'll need to tell it to run a certain command each time the container boots up.  You can do this using CMD.

```
# Add this to your Dockerfile
RUN yum install -y --setopt=skip_missing_names_on_install=False nmap-ncat
COPY cmd.sh /usr/local/bin/cmd.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cmd.sh
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/cmd.sh"]
```

Finally, we'll need to set up port-forwarding in cmd.sh.  I found that `nc`, even with the `-l` and `-k` options, will occasionally terminate when a request is completed, so I'm using a while-loop to ensure that it's always running.

```
# cmd.sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

while nc -l -p 6379 -k -c "nc redis 6379" || true; do true; done &

tail -f /dev/null # Or any other command that never exits
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to access `redis` from the host (127.0.0.1), you have to use the `ports` command.

```
redis:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-redis
    ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

Comment: that creates circular dependency, which makes sense.  I already have that on nodejs

Comment: @z.a. I might have misunderstood what you want, I updated my post it now exposes the 6379 to the host (and any other machines on the network unless you have a firewall).

Comment: hmm, that also won't work I am afraid.  this is not necessary to expose port to the nodejs container.  ports: exposes ports to the actual host machine.  I want to map rdis 6379 port to the nodejs 6379 port.