# docker-compose ports not mapping; logs shows app is running

Tags: docker, flask

When I run `flask run` the localhost port is exposed and the application loads with no errors, but when I run `docker-compose up -d --build` the image is built and running but the localhost is not exposed. inspecting the container shows that it built with no errors and is still running. I've reviewed [this github issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4799) and [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429837/docker-compose-port-mapping) which suggested `network_host mode` was the problem but I am not using it. It also suggested manually using 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 in the ports mapping but that didn't help.

docker-compose.yml

```
#~/Projects/mysite/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  flask-dev:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    image: "site-development"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ".:/personal_site"
    tty: true
```

Dockerfile

```
#~/Projects/mysite/Dockerfile
# multi build stages
#https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

# ==================================== BASE ====================================
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster AS base

WORKDIR /personal_site

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV FLASK_APP mysite
ENV FLASK_ENV development
ENV FLASK_DEBUG 1


RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    gcc

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY . .

# ================================= DEVELOPMENT ================================
FROM base as development
COPY ./requirements-dev.txt /personal_site/requirements-dev.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements-dev.txt

CMD ["flask", "run"]

# ================================= PRODUCTION =================================
FROM base as production
COPY ./requirements-prod.txt /personal_site/requirements-prod.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements-prod.txt

# =================================== MANAGE ===================================
FROM base as manage
COPY ./requirements-dev.txt /personal_site/requirements-dev.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
```

Docker versions:

```
docker-compose version 1.25.5, build 8a1c60f6
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
```

Folder Structure:

```
#~/Projects/mysite
- docker-compose.yml
- Dockerfile
- mysite/__init__.py
```

Running from cmd with `flask run`

```
 * Serving Flask app "mysite" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 331-834-605
```

Docker-compose stout

```
stephen@stephen:~/Projects/mysite$ docker-compose up -d --build
docker-compose up -d --build
Building flask-dev
Step 1/15 : FROM python:3.8-slim-buster AS base
 ---> 6cf621cb1327
Step 2/15 : WORKDIR /personal_site
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 751c8aa117f3
Step 3/15 : ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8b29a6862b7a
Step 4/15 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a5f8751c9c12
Step 5/15 : ENV FLASK_APP mysite
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bc212892cc17
Step 6/15 : ENV FLASK_ENV development
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9ffa29dcea47
Step 7/15 : ENV FLASK_DEBUG 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9b2e876d307a
Step 8/15 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bd323216e65a
Step 9/15 : RUN apt-get install -y  gcc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3105c1727b5d
Step 10/15 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6f8fb5bc0015
Step 11/15 : COPY . .
 ---> 76ff5e26c0a9

Step 12/15 : FROM base as development
 ---> 76ff5e26c0a9
Step 13/15 : COPY ./requirements-dev.txt /personal_site/requirements-dev.txt
 ---> 06e9dac6dec6
Step 14/15 : RUN pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
 ---> Running in f4743afd3a31
Collecting click==7.1.2
  Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting Flask==1.1.2
  Downloading Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous==1.1.0
  Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Jinja2==2.11.2
  Downloading Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe==1.1.1
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (32 kB)
Collecting Werkzeug==1.0.1
  Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
Collecting pytest==6.0.2
  Downloading pytest-6.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (270 kB)
Collecting black==19.10b0
  Downloading black-19.10b0-py36-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting flake8==3.8.3
  Downloading flake8-3.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
Collecting flake8-blind-except==0.1.1
  Downloading flake8-blind-except-0.1.1.tar.gz (2.5 kB)
Collecting flake8-debugger==3.2.1
  Downloading flake8-debugger-3.2.1.tar.gz (4.2 kB)
Collecting flake8-docstrings==1.5.0
  Downloading flake8_docstrings-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
Collecting flake8-isort==4.0.0
  Downloading flake8_isort-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting isort==5.5.2
  Downloading isort-5.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Collecting pep8-naming==0.11.1
  Downloading pep8_naming-0.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.4 kB)
Collecting pluggy<1.0,>=0.12
  Downloading pluggy-0.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting toml
  Downloading toml-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting more-itertools>=4.0.0
  Downloading more_itertools-8.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.4.0
  Downloading attrs-20.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting py>=1.8.2
  Downloading py-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (99 kB)
Collecting iniconfig
  Downloading iniconfig-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
Collecting packaging
  Downloading packaging-20.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting appdirs
  Downloading appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting regex
  Downloading regex-2020.9.27-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (675 kB)
Collecting pathspec<1,>=0.6
  Downloading pathspec-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting typed-ast>=1.4.0
  Downloading typed_ast-1.4.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (768 kB)
Collecting pyflakes<2.3.0,>=2.2.0
  Downloading pyflakes-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Collecting mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
  Downloading mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.6 kB)
Collecting pycodestyle<2.7.0,>=2.6.0a1
  Downloading pycodestyle-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flake8-blind-except==0.1.1->-r requirements-dev.txt (line 10)) (50.3.0)
Collecting pydocstyle>=2.1
  Downloading pydocstyle-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting testfixtures<7,>=6.8.0
  Downloading testfixtures-6.14.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
Collecting flake8-polyfill<2,>=1.0.2
  Downloading flake8_polyfill-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.3 kB)
Collecting six
  Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2
  Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting snowballstemmer
  Downloading snowballstemmer-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: flake8-blind-except, flake8-debugger
  Building wheel for flake8-blind-except (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for flake8-blind-except (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for flake8-blind-except: filename=flake8_blind_except-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl size=3045 sha256=ee8ec372f4ef9ba5aa472cc70cf2b34462c2e5742c4431a88d4811ba3c6941b9
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/7f/70/4f/6002af5c24a072eec72570bf0a265bf95f1968c4508563b6cd
  Building wheel for flake8-debugger (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for flake8-debugger (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for flake8-debugger: filename=flake8_debugger-3.2.1-py3-none-any.whl size=4201 sha256=0399bc5b93a43d4f70912c25e9251000b1003a04215c0d3b0656da88f0fd828b
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/39/b8/cc/049c8f7f02a46a88305db6b9ed26799fded45f98e20728640c
Successfully built flake8-blind-except flake8-debugger
Installing collected packages: click, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, Flask, pluggy, toml, more-itertools, attrs, py, iniconfig, six, pyparsing, packaging, pytest, appdirs, regex, pathspec, typed-ast, black, pyflakes, mccabe, pycodestyle, flake8, flake8-blind-except, flake8-debugger, snowballstemmer, pydocstyle, flake8-docstrings, isort, testfixtures, flake8-isort, flake8-polyfill, pep8-naming
Successfully installed Flask-1.1.2 Jinja2-2.11.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 appdirs-1.4.4 attrs-20.2.0 black-19.10b0 click-7.1.2 flake8-3.8.3 flake8-blind-except-0.1.1 flake8-debugger-3.2.1 flake8-docstrings-1.5.0 flake8-isort-4.0.0 flake8-polyfill-1.0.2 iniconfig-1.0.1 isort-5.5.2 itsdangerous-1.1.0 mccabe-0.6.1 more-itertools-8.5.0 packaging-20.4 pathspec-0.8.0 pep8-naming-0.11.1 pluggy-0.13.1 py-1.9.0 pycodestyle-2.6.0 pydocstyle-5.1.1 pyflakes-2.2.0 pyparsing-2.4.7 pytest-6.0.2 regex-2020.9.27 six-1.15.0 snowballstemmer-2.0.0 testfixtures-6.14.2 toml-0.10.1 typed-ast-1.4.1
Removing intermediate container f4743afd3a31
 ---> c63db68e69d5
Step 15/15 : CMD ["flask", "run"]
 ---> Running in c0f90d383fb2
Removing intermediate container c0f90d383fb2
 ---> 8552c5d064ca

Successfully built 8552c5d064ca
Successfully tagged site-development:latest
Recreating mysite_flask-dev_1 ... 
stephen@stephen:~/Projects/mysite$ docker-compose ps
docker-compose ps
       Name           Command    State           Ports         
---------------------------------------------------------------
mysite_flask-dev_1   flask run   Up      0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp
stephen@stephen:~/Projects/mysite$ docker-compose logs
docker-compose logs
Attaching to mysite_flask-dev_1
flask-dev_1  |  * Tip: There are .env or .flaskenv files present. Do "pip install python-dotenv" to use them.
flask-dev_1  |  * Serving Flask app "mysite" (lazy loading)
flask-dev_1  |  * Environment: development
flask-dev_1  |  * Debug mode: on
flask-dev_1  |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
flask-dev_1  |  * Restarting with stat
flask-dev_1  |  * Tip: There are .env or .flaskenv files present. Do "pip install python-dotenv" to use them.
flask-dev_1  |  * Debugger is active!
flask-dev_1  |  * Debugger PIN: 124-299-806
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `EXPOSE 5000` to your Dockerfile? See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: @RobertNubel yes. I actually had that command in there but deleted it. Docker-compose ports exposes and publishes the ports. At least that is what I understood from the documentation.

Comment: Right, though it might be helpful to run just the container to determine if it's a compose issue or not. Looking at the docker compose quick start guide, though, the example app happens to be a Flask app and the only difference I can really see is that they're setting `ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0`, which might help Flask listen correctly.

Comment: @RobertNubel yea o was using that guide too. I wanted to keep as much as I could in the compose file which is why I deleted the expose command. I didn’t notice the env variable so I’ll take a look at that. To be honest idk the equivalent docket run commands, I only now how to use socket-compose. It seems like a lot more verbose of commands to use run to get the ports mapped etc so I didn’t want to debug that way unless I had to. Was hoping someone could point at on obvious bug

Comment: @RobertNubel well sir you have done it. I needed the FLASK_RUN_HOSt env. Now time to figure out what it does. I set the host machine to 0.0.0.0:5000 in the .yml ports mapping so not sure what the difference is.

Comment: So Flask needs to be told to listen on 0.0.0.0 specifically, because then it listens on every network interface and not just the loopback (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost) -- so, binding it to 127.0.0.1 would work on your bare metal, but not in a VM or docker container. The port mapping change you tried, though, was I believe mapping port 5000 bound to your *host's* 0.0.0.0, and wasn't affecting the container at all.

Answer (score 0):

Per [docker quickstart guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) you need to set the `ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0` in the Dockerfile.

Moved @robert's helpful comment to an answer

"So Flask needs to be told to listen on 0.0.0.0 specifically because then it listens on every network interface and not just the loopback (see: [stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)) -- so, binding it to 127.0.0.1 would work on your bare metal, but not in a VM or docker container. The port mapping change you tried, though, was I believe mapping port 5000 bound to your host's 0.0.0.0, and wasn't affecting the container at all."